# In template: no matching constructor for initialization in a vector

Tags: c++

I making a vector of pairs of custom types, but I can't compile with it...

I am looking to store pointers to Factory functions. Currently I store `IOperand*` but it doesn't seem to be the right type to put

I made this vector in a class:

```
    class Factory
{
    public:
        Factory();
        static IOperand* createOperand(eOperandType type, const std::string& value);
        ~Factory();

    protected:
    private:

        static IOperand* createInt8(const std::string& value);
        static IOperand* createInt16(const std::string& value);
        static IOperand* createInt32(const std::string& value);
        static IOperand* createFloat(const std::string& value);
        static IOperand* createDouble(const std::string& value);
        static IOperand* createBigDecimal(const std::string& value);
        std::vector<std::pair<std::string, eOperandType>> operands;
        std::vector<std::pair<eOperandType, IOperand*>> operands_factory;
};
```

My first vector is working fine, but the second isn't working:

```
   Factory::Factory()
{
    //Working fine
    operands.emplace_back("bigdecimal", BIGDECIMAL);
    //emplace_back isn't working
    operands_factory.emplace_back(std::make_pair(INT8, &Factory::createInt8));
}
```

Here is the error from the compiler:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:145:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<eOperandType, IOperand*>::pair(std::pair<eOperandType, IOperand* (*)(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>)’
```

My IOperand interface is described as below:

```
class IOperand
{
    public:
        virtual std::string toString() const = 0;
        virtual eOperandType getType() const = 0;
        virtual IOperand* operator+(const IOperand & rhs) const = 0;
        virtual IOperand* operator-(const IOperand & rhs) const = 0;
        virtual IOperand* operator*(const IOperand & rhs) const = 0;
        virtual IOperand* operator/(const IOperand & rhs) const = 0;
        virtual IOperand* operator%(const IOperand & rhs) const = 0;
        virtual ~IOperand() {}
};
```

So I really don't know how can I fix it and why...

Comment: what is `IOperand` ? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `&Factory::createInt8` seems to be a member function pointer, `IOperand*` is a plain pointer.

Comment: also `Factory::createInt8` is completely missing in the code you posted.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, I've not even coded the function, I first put functions in a vector. The function actually return a nullptr

Comment: `operands_factory` is expecting a `IOperand*` as second value of the pair, but you are trying to pass it a pointer to a function which has a `IOperand*` return type. Clearly these are not the same thing. Did you maybe intend to _call_ the function instead of forming a pointer to it? Or maybe you actually do want to store member function pointers in `operands_factory`? The question is lacking context for us to figure this out.

Comment: I try to store member function pointers in operands_factory. I'm a beginner, do you have some documentation about that?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is actually just a regular function pointer going by the error message. It may be a `static` function.

Comment: @rootmeih The syntax in the error messages shows how you write out the type of a function pointer. For example if you want to store pointers to functions which take a `const std::string&` and return a `IOperand*`, then the type should be `IOperand* (*)(const std::string&)` instead of `IOperand*`.

Comment: Oooh okay that's it! I didn't get that from the message

Comment: This question is answerable without [mcve] but it could be clearer. In current state, you mostly have to decipher what the code is like. I don't have time for such a task right now; maybe someone else has. The question could be much clearer if it had [mcve].

Comment: I will try to shed some light on the issue